# Use Varchar variable in FROM statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, variables, select, varchar, declare

I'm wondering if there is a way, after pragmatically giving a Varchar variable a value, to use that variable in the From Statement? We have archive tables that will cycle out and back in.  So, the table can go missing for several days and when they cycle back in they change the table name to end w/ the current year (Ex. 012015 when before it was 012014.)  Because of this my query can throw up object errors and I'm the only guy on my team that understands the simple error and how to quickly fix the stupid thing. below is the solution I'm trying to get to work, but I keep getting the error "Must declare the table variable @Jan."  I totally understand what a table variable is and how to use it and that is obviously not what I want to do here.  Is there any way to use a varchar variable (or other similar variable type) in the From Statement?  Code below:

```
Declare @Jan Varchar(40)

IF OBJECT_ID('ColTelephonyArchive.dbo.ACDSkill201401') IS NOT NULL
Begin
    Set @Jan = 'ColTelephonyArchive.dbo.ACDSkill201401'
 END

     IF OBJECT_ID('ColTelephonyArchive.dbo.ACDSkill201501') IS NOT NULL
        Begin
            Set @Jan = 'ColTelephonyArchive.dbo.ACDSkill201501'
        END

            IF @Jan IS NULL
                Begin
                    Set @Jan = 'Does.Not.Exist'
                END

Select WorkDte, SwitchNbr, SkillNbr,StaffTimeInSec, AvailableTimeInSec, ACDCallTotCt 
        ,AbandonCallTotCt, AbandonCall1Ct, AnswerTimeInSec, ACDTalkTimeInSec,TotAcwTimeInSec, HoldTimeInSec 
FROM @Jan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting your problem right, you need to build the dynamic query. So in your case it would be

```
DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(511)
SET @qry = 'Select WorkDte, SwitchNbr, SkillNbr,StaffTimeInSec, AvailableTimeInSec, ACDCallTotCt 
    ,AbandonCallTotCt, AbandonCall1Ct, AnswerTimeInSec, ACDTalkTimeInSec,TotAcwTimeInSec, HoldTimeInSec 
FROM ' + @Jan

EXEC (@qry)
```

Comment: This is good stuff and works, however it doesnt seem that I can't Insert this data from the EXEC(@qry) into a temp table or UNION it in any way...is it possible to UNION or store data from the EXEC...or can it only display the results?

Comment: Never mind...I just created a table and used INSERT INTO #MyTempTable, right above the EXEC command...worked perfectly

Comment: Thanks Alex A.  you put me in the right direction with the above answer.  Got my code doing exactly what I want now...

Comment: I'm glad that helped! You could build and execute any type of query inside the text string "SET @qry = 'INSERT INTO #MyTempTable SELECT * FROM ' +@jan EXEC @qry"